# NextJS build not including API file

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am having a Nextjs project with version `13.4.7`. I've created a file under api folder with path `src/app/api/send-mail/route.js`. Here I defined one POST API to send an email. Everything is working fine on local. But when I am deploying my site, build is not including API file.

Here is my API file:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export async function POST(request) {
let response;
try {
const req = await request.json();

console.log(req, "REQ");

const msg = {
  to: "test@yopmail.com",
  from: "test1@gmail.com",
  subject: "test subject",
  html: `Sample HTML"
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
    response = { "message": "Email sent succesfully.", "status": 200 };
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "ERROR");
    response = { "message": "Something went wrong.", "status": 400 };
  });
 } catch (err) {
   response = { "message": "Something went wrong." };
   console.log(err, "ERROR");
 }
return NextResponse.json({...response});
}
```

Here is the output of my `npm run build` command:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tjwM.png): [image: Build output]https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHXHF.png

Comment: Isn’t your api route supposed to be located at `src/app/api/send-mail/route.js`? I’m wondering how it’s even working locally.

Comment: Yes, Edited in the post description

Comment: How do you determine the fact that the build is not including your api route? Is your api route not working? Or are you looking at `0` in the build output `size` column? Next.js is lying to you...

Comment: I was looking at 0B. Thanks a lot for help. It was an issue with my code only. I was not awaiting for the response of sgMail.send.